# Is there ST_Intersects alternative that allows two(or more) polygons to share sides

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, intersection

I am using ST_Intersects to check if two polygons intersect. Relevant part of my query is:

```
SELECT entity_number
FROM coordinates
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS($1, location)
```

It works well to determine if one polygon crosses the other's surface:

[image]

I expected ST_Intersects to return false when two polygons share sides, but it does not:

[image]

I read about other methods like `ST_Covers, ST_Contains, ST_ContainsProperly, ST_Within ,ST_DWithin`. But i am not sure which one suits my needs.

Is there any method that allows two polygons to share sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`ST_Overlaps`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.3/ST_Overlaps.html):

> Returns TRUE if geometry A and B "spatially overlap". Two geometries overlap if they have the same dimension, each has at least one point not shared by the other (or equivalently neither covers the other), and the intersection of their interiors has the same dimension. The overlaps relationship is symmetrical.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Laurenz, [`ST_Overlaps`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Overlaps.html) is what you're looking for. However, quite often it does not suffice to simply check if polygons do overlap, but also "how much" they overlap. In other words, how much of *geometry a* overlaps with *geometry b*? [`ST_Intersection`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) returns a polygon that is the result of the intersection of two geometries, so you can [`ST_Area`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html) this generated polygon and compare it with one of the polygons given to the function, e.g. given these polygons ..

[image]

... this would be the result of `ST_Intersection`

[image]

And this is how you could calculate the percentage of the overlap

```
SELECT 
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(g1,g2))/ST_Area(g1)*100 AS perc_g1_overlap,
  ST_Intersection(g1,g2)
FROM t;

  perc_g1_overlap   |                                                                                          st_intersection                                                                                           
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 16.555309365086124 | 0103000020E6100000010000000500000054435ACF861E12C02068AC4B11214B4054435ACFD60A12C02068AC4B11214B4054435ACFD60A12C04B266CCD791F4B4054435ACF861E12C04B266CCD791F4B4054435ACF861E12C02068AC4B11214B40
(1 row)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/yvNB8u8k)

Comment: Very necessary addition. thanks

Comment: Is there a way to find the coordinates where the polygons overlap ?
I need to trace a median using theses 2 points ...

Comment: @user10078 if you mean to retrieve a point from the overlapping area you might wanna take a look at ST_Centroid, e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/G7UavJQ0